# Does every every singleton set in a Hausdorff space have no limit points?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that every singleton set in a Hausdorff space has no limit points? Here's my attempt at a proof:

> Let $x \in X$ Hausdorff and consider the one-point set $\{x\}$. Let $y$ be a limit point of $\{x\}$. Then by def. every neighborhood of $y$ intersects $\{x\}$ at some point other than itself. If $y \in \{x\}$ then $y=x$, but then $X$ is a neighborhood of $y$ such that $X \cap \{x\} = \{x\} = \{y\}$, a contradiction. If $y \notin \{x\}$ then $x$ and $y$ are distinct, so there exist neighborhoods $U_{x}$ and $U_y$ such that $U_{x} \cap U_y = \emptyset$. Since $\{x\} \subset U_x$ it follows that $\{x\} \cap U_y = \emptyset$, a contradiction. Thus $\{x\}$ has no limit points.

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: I believe your proof is fine, just double checking in the first case you just end up with a contradictions since the point in the neighborhood cannot be $x$ itself by definition?

Comment: @a.s. graduate student yup

Comment: @guest alright, seems good then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct, although it can be generalized to $T_1$-spaces:

Suppose $x \in X$, where $X$ is a $T_1$-space. As you have shown, $x$ is not a limit point of {$x$}. On the other hand, if $y \neq x \in X$, we have that $X \setminus${x} is an open nhood of $y$ in $X$, which is disjoint from {x} (giving us $y$ is not a limit point of {$x$}).

It should be noted that it does not hold for $T_0$-spaces:

Consider $X =$ {$0,1$} with the Sierpiński topology (i.e., $\emptyset$, {$0$}, and $X$ are the only open sets). Then {$0$} has $1$ as a limit point.